# How to change the format of SQLAlchemy engine 'echo' messages?

Tags: sqlalchemy

IIUC, the format is set in log.py (lines 33..38 in 1.4.7):

```
def _add_default_handler(logger):
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setFormatter(
        logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s")
    )
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

But all my attempts to set the format to a bare '%(message)s' have failed.  For example,

```
logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout).setFormatter('%(message)s')
```

has no effect.

When developing a program in SQLAlchemy, I want to see only the query executed by engine, and these extra fields `asctime`, `levelname` and `name` are distracting.

There is an [entire subchapter about engine logging](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#configuring-logging) in SQLAlchemy documentation, but it talks only about levels and says nothing about formatting.  On the other hand, I guess changing formatting should be possible, because in SQLAlchemy tutorial (see, e.g., [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/metadata.html#emitting-ddl-to-the-database)), the logging messages are presented just the way I would like them.

Answer (score 1):

First some remarks:

1. When you write
   : `logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)`
   you're calling a constructor, i.e. you're getting a **new instance of
   logging.StreamHandler** class, not the same handler which could have been used in
   sqla's log module: `_add_default_handler()`.
   Modifying it won't have any effect as long as you don't add this handler to some active logger.
2. It you read carefully the docs page you mentionned (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#configuring-logging), you'll find some hints :

> It’s important to note that these two flags work *independently* of
> any existing logging configuration, and will make use of
> logging.basicConfig() unconditionally. This has the effect of being
> configured *in addition* to any existing logger configurations.
> Therefore, *when configuring logging explicitly, ensure all echo flags
> are set to False at all times*, to avoid getting duplicate log lines.

`logging.basicConfig()` accepts a good set of parameters, but deals only with
the *root logger*, from which other loggers will inherit settings.

As a first step I suggest you keep the level and logger name in output, to let
you know *who is speaking* in your messages.

```
>>> import logging
>>> # 1. Get rid of timestamp for all modules, and set other defaults
... logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s %(name)s %(message)s", level="INFO")
... logging.info("Root logger talking")
... 
INFO root Root logger talking
>>> # 2. Preset top level logger for SQLAlchemy
... logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').setLevel("INFO")
... 
>>> # 4. Run your code
... import sqlalchemy as sqla
... engine = sqla.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
... 
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
... 
... Base = declarative_base()
... from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
>>> class User(Base):
...     __tablename__ = 'users'
... 
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
...     name = Column(String)
... 
INFO sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper (User|users) _configure_property(id, Column)
INFO sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper (User|users) _configure_property(name, Column)
INFO sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper (User|users) Identified primary key columns: ColumnSet([Column('id', Integer(), table=<users>, primary_key=True, nullable=False)])
INFO sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper (User|users) constructed
>>> Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("users")
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine PRAGMA temp.table_info("users")
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
>>>
```

To answer your question more specifically, here's a solution:

```py
      import logging, sys

      sql_logger = logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine")
      hdlr = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
      hdlr.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("[SQL] %(message)s"))
      sql_logger.addHandler(hdlr)
      sql_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

      import sqlalchemy as sqla
      engine = sqla.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

      from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

      Base = declarative_base()
      from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
      class User(Base):
          __tablename__ = 'users'

          id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
          name = Column(String)

      Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

You'll need some more work to handle other modules log messages,
while avoiding duplicates

Answer (score 0):

To format sqlalchemy log, try this way

```py
import sys
import logging
import logging.config
LOGGING_CONFIG = dict(
    version=1,
    disable_existing_loggers=False,
    loggers={
        "sqlalchemy.engine": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "handlers": ["sqlalchemy_console"],
            "propagate": True,
            "qualname": "sqlalchemy.engine",
        },
    },
    handlers={
        "sqlalchemy_console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "sqlalchemy",
            "stream": sys.stdout,
        },
    },
    formatters={
        "sqlalchemy": {
            "format": "%(message)s",
            "datefmt": "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z]",
            "class": "logging.Formatter",
        },
    }
)
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)
logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy.engine")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).